# How to format SQL Queries inside PySpark codefile

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, format, prettify

I would like to format my existing SQL queries inside the PySpark file.

This is how my existing source file looks like:

```
from flow import flow
f = flow(["xxx"], ["xxxxxxxx"])
# this is a comment
f.spark.sql(
    """ select dealer_number location_path_id, '2099-12-31' location_path_end_date, dealer_to_salespoint(dealer_number) sales_point_id, true can_rollup_owner, dealer_number entity, 5 as location_level, calendar_date, 'Sales' period_type, coalesce(m.model,'OTH') model_id, 'daily' as cadence, cpo_coverage_code, cpo_contract_status, 'cpo'  feed_name from ( select *, row_number() over (partition by a.dealer_number, a.cpo_contract_number, a.cpo_contract_status order by a.calendar_date asc, a.filekey desc) rn from ( select `DEALER NUMBER` dealer_number, `CONTRACT STATUS` cpo_contract_status,`COVERAGE CODE` cpo_coverage_code, `CONTRACT NUMBER` cpo_contract_number, `vehicle model` cpo_vehicle_model, to_date(`CONTRACT TRANSACTION DATE`) calendar_date, filekey, * from cpo_v1 ) a ) f where f.rn = 1 """
)
```

And this is how I wanted it to look like:

```
from flow import flow

f = flow(["xxx"],["abc"],filename=True)

f.spark.sql("""
 select    
     dealer location_path_id,
     '2099-12-31' location_path_end_date,
     dealer_to_salespoint(dealer_number) sales_point_id,
     true can_rollup_owner,
     dealer_number entity,
     5 as location_level,
     calendar_date,
     'Sales' period_type,
     coalesce(m.model,'OTH') model_id,
     'daily' as cadence,
     cpo_coverage_code,
     cpo_contract_status,
     'cpo'  feed_name
   from (
       select *,
          row_number() over (partition by a.dealer_number, a.cpo_contract_number, a.cpo_contract_status
                                   order by a.calendar_date asc, a.filekey desc) rn
        from (
            select 
                `DEALER NUMBER` dealer_number,
                `CONTRACT STATUS` cpo_contract_status,
                `COVERAGE CODE` cpo_coverage_code,
                `CONTRACT NUMBER` cpo_contract_number,
                `vehicle model` cpo_vehicle_model,
                to_date(`CONTRACT TRANSACTION DATE`) calendar_date,
                filekey,
                *
            from cpo_v1
            ) a
    ) f
    left join (
            select 
                model,
                alternate_model_name
            from models_v1
            lateral view explode(nvl2(alternate_modelname, split(model_name || ',' || alternate_modelname, ","), split(model_name, ","))) as alternate_model_name
            ) m 
            on lower(split(f.cpo_vehicle_model,' ')[0]) = lower(m.alternate_model_name)
    where
    f.rn = 1
"""
).createOrReplaceTempView("xxx")

f.save_view("xxx")
```

I have already tried using black and other vscode extensions for formatting my code base but no luck since the SQL code is being treated as a python string. Please suggest any workaround

P.S.: I'm having an existing codebase of more than 700+ such files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible options is to use [`sql-formatter`](https://pypi.org/project/sql-formatter/).

Let's say we have a `test.py` file:

```py
from flow import flow

f = flow(["xxx"], ["xxxxxxxx"])
f.spark.sql(
    """ select dealer_number location_path_id, '2099-12-31' location_path_end_date, dealer_to_salespoint(dealer_number) sales_point_id, true can_rollup_owner, dealer_number entity, 5 as location_level, calendar_date, 'Sales' period_type, coalesce(m.model,'OTH') model_id, 'daily' as cadence, cpo_coverage_code, cpo_contract_status, 'cpo'  feed_name from ( select *, row_number() over (partition by a.dealer_number, a.cpo_contract_number, a.cpo_contract_status order by a.calendar_date asc, a.filekey desc) rn from ( select `DEALER NUMBER` dealer_number, `CONTRACT STATUS` cpo_contract_status,`COVERAGE CODE` cpo_coverage_code, `CONTRACT NUMBER` cpo_contract_number, `vehicle model` cpo_vehicle_model, to_date(`CONTRACT TRANSACTION DATE`) calendar_date, filekey, * from cpo_v1 ) a ) f where f.rn = 1 """
)
```

We can create a script that will read the file as string, find queries by searching for `"""`, extract them, run them through formatter and replace them:

```py
import re
from sql_formatter.core import format_sql

with open("test.py", "r") as f_in:
    text = f_in.read()
    text = re.sub('"""(.*)"""', lambda x: format_sql(x.group()), text)
    with open("test.py", "w") as f_out:
        f_out.write(text)
```

Comment: @AnujSharma What doesn't work? I've tested it with your example, it worked.

Comment: I just tweaked the regex according to my preference now it's working.

Comment: @AnujSharma Great to hear that! I'm glad I helped.